# Java "import.java.util.Scanner" Error on Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

A beginner Java programmer here using JDK 17 with latest Eclipse IDE.

I'm getting this syntax error here when I'm trying to use "import" keyword.
My Eclipse showing "import java.util.Scanner;" as warning
and when I'm trying to run I'm getting some weird output.

One more thing everything is running properly with IntelliJ, The problem is with Eclipse IDE I guess. Is there any way to fix this?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    
    System.out.print("\n");
    
    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String x = userinput.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Hello " + userinput);

}

}
```

Output:

> What is your name? Paul
> Hello java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=6][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\x{2c}][decimal separator=\x{2e}][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\QNaN\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]

Comment: You need to use `System.out.print("Hello " + x);`

Comment: What is the complete warning message that Eclipse is showing?  (Please enter it as text in your question.)   The IDE problem is most likely that the Eclipse settings that select the target platform are not set properly and the IDE's builtin compiler cannot find the package or class the warning is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You're outputting the wrong variable. Try switching `userinput` (Scanner object) with `x` (First line of the input).
Like this:

```
System.out.print("Hello " + x);
```